# empty constructor while using bitmap

Tags: c#, console, bitmap

i have problem with using bitmap in console application in c#.
I included system.drawing reference to work but while writing code the intelisense shows there isn't any suggestion for bitmap(X); (where X it the suggestion).

I am using C# 2010 express edition, created console application and added system drawing reference. I have problem with code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(); // problem it that i don't see any suggestion from intelisense, but i need insert parameters
```

Hope i write logically, sorry for english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're not referencing the `Bitmap` class from namespace `System.Drawing` -- fully qualifying the namspace may help (if you've got a conflicting `Bitmap` class from a different namespace) - also make sure that you're referencing the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly

Comment: that's right :) i accidentialy created bitmap.cs with Bitmap class which the program was refferencing to, instead to .net standard class. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from [Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) does not have a public parameterless constructor.

You have to use one of the constructors provided in the list on the provided page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are not getting any intellisense suggestion, but just have a look on the [Bitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.bitmap.bitmap%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) overview. There you can see the various contructors you can use in order to create a new `Bitmap` instance. You should also check there is not a conflicting `Bitmap` class in another referenced library.